# Render LaTeX from IPython output in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, latex, ipython

Suppose I have a simple ipython program and I want to display some LaTeX math:

```py
from IPython.display import display, Math

display(Math("\\frac{a}{b}"))
```

Running in the terminal, I get the following output:

```bash
$ ipython main.py
<IPython.core.display.Math object>
```

Is it possible to properly render the math output in the terminal? (without using a notebook gui)

Comment: Briefly, no. Terminals don't really have the concept of a "font", and you need special fonts to display LaTeX.